# how to configure proper credentials in OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap

I don't understand how to configure users and passwords on the OpenLDAP server. What I describe in this question is based on a clean install of OpenLDAP 2.4 on Centos 7 (via yum).

After starting `slapd` I perform the command

```
[root@papp ~]# slapcat -n0 | grep olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com
```

This tells me that we already have a root user with the dn `cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com`. That user has no password set.

```
[root@papp ~]# slapcat -n0 | grep olcRootPW
```

Next I try to set the password manually:

```
[root@papp ~]# ldappasswd -H ldap://localhost -x -D "dn=Manager,dc=my-           
domain,dc=com" -W -A -S  
Old password: (empty)
Re-enter old password: (empty)
New password: password
Re-enter new password: password
Enter LDAP Password: (what is that?? I use empty)
ldap_bind: Invalid DN syntax (34)
additional info: invalid DN
```

Which gives me an invalid DN. Why is that ? I don't see an invalid DN. Does it mean that I cannot use the `ldappasswd` command on a clean install of OpenLDAP?

Next I try to upload a schema file

```
# /tmp/pass.ldif
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: password

[root@papp ~]# ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /tmp/pass.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config"
```

The password has now been set, as I can confirm via

```
[root@papp ~]# slapcat -n0 | grep olcRootPW
olcRootPW:: cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

However a search does still not work

```
ldapsearch -D "cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com" -v -x -b '' -s base  '(objectClass=*)' -w password
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

I also tried to use apache directory studio to browse my LDAP tree but I can only connect to ldap using 'no authentication'. As soon as I use simple authentication with dn = `cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com` I get an authentication error (invalid credentials).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first thing is first: Don't set a clear text password, even though the configuration is hashing it in some way. Use `slappasswd` first. Second, you can't use `ldappasswd` for the directory manager. Third, I'm not sure, but something tells me something else is misconfigured, and you haven't made it clear how you changed your olcRootDN.

I tried to repeat what you did, but could not reproduce the same errors or issues.

```
# yum install openldap-servers -y
# systemctl start slapd
# slappasswd
New password:
Re-enter new password: 
{SSHA}piJmuKxgnMh7DVBOQtCgz3/httcjc4kP

# /tmp/manager.ldif
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=manager,dc=angelsofclockwork,dc=net
-
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}piJmuKxgnMh7DVBOQtCgz3/httcjc4kP

# ldapmodify -QY EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /tmp/manager.ldif

# ldapsearch -D "cn=Manager,dc=bromosapien,dc=net" -v -x -b '' -s base  '(objectClass=*)' -W -h localhost
ldap_initialize( ldap://localhost )
Enter LDAP Password:
filter: (objectClass=*)
requesting: All userApplication attributes
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <> with scope baseObject
# filter: (objectClass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

#
dn:
objectClass: top
objectClass: OpenLDAProotDSE

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

You may want to read a guide to help you walkthrough/understand the steps you need to take. http://www.angelsofclockwork.net/wiki/centos/openldap.html

Comment: I think I know where the problem was: the `base dn` of the attributes `olcRootDN and olcRootPW` was not the same as the base dn for the query I made. Following your instructions it was easy correct the query. Thanks for your help.